# Rerender child when parent state is updated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I am currently creating a MultiCheckbox Component like:

*Checkbox.tsx*

```
import './Checkbox.scss';

import React, {ChangeEvent, Component,} from 'react';

/*
 * The properties of Checkbox
 */
interface ICheckboxProps<TYPE> {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    value: TYPE;
    checked?: boolean;
    //if a cross should be used instead of a hook
    cross?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    //should show a label on the right side of the checkbox
    showLabel?: boolean;
    //get the string for the value of the checkbox
    labelFunc?: (value: TYPE) => string;
    // an onChange function which gets called with the state.checked argument
    onChange?: (checkbox: ICheckboxState<TYPE>) => void;
}

interface ICheckboxState<TYPE> {
    // checked state of the checkbox
    checked: boolean;
    value: TYPE;
}

class CheckboxComponent<TYPE> extends Component<ICheckboxProps<TYPE>, ICheckboxState<TYPE>> {
    constructor(props: ICheckboxProps<TYPE>) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
        // set the initial state
        this.state = {
            checked: props.checked == null ? false : props.checked,
            value: props.value,
        };
        console.log(props);
    }

    /*
     * Render the component as ReactElement
     */
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        console.log('Checkbox render: ');
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <div className={'checkbox'}>
                <input
                    id={this.props.id}
                    type={'checkbox'}
                    name={this.props.name}
                    className={this.props.cross === true ? 'checkbox-cross' : 'checkbox-hook'}
                    onChange={this.onInputElementChangeEvent}
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                    disabled={this.props.disabled}
                />
                {this.props.showLabel === true ? (
                    <label
                        className="checkbox-label"
                        htmlFor={this.props.id}>
                        {typeof this.props.labelFunc === 'function' ?
                            this.props.labelFunc(this.state.value) : String(this.state.value)}
                    </label>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        );
    }

    private onInputElementChangeEvent = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        this.onChange(e.target.checked);
    }

    private onChange(checked: boolean): void {
        // set the new state when the "onChange" event of the checkbox happens
        this.setState({
            checked: checked,
            value: this.state.value,
        }, () => {
            // if there is an onChange function supscribed to the event handler than execute it with the current "checked" as
            if (typeof this.props.onChange === 'function') {
                this.props.onChange(this.state);
            }
        });
    }

    public isChecked(): boolean {
        return this.state.checked;
    }

    //return only the value if it's checked
    public getValue(): TYPE {
        return this.state.value;
    }
}

export const Checkbox = (CheckboxComponent);
```

and the

*MultiCheckbox.tsx*

```
import './MultiCheckbox.scss';

import React, {Component,} from 'react';
import {Checkbox} from "../Checkbox";

/*
 * The properties of Checkbox
 */
interface IMultiCheckboxProps<TYPE> {
    id: string;
    values: TYPE[];
    idFunc: (value: TYPE) => any;
    //if a cross should be used instead of a hook
    cross?: boolean;
    initialChecked?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    //get the string for the value of the checkbox
    labelFunc: (value: TYPE) => string;
    // an onChange function which gets called with the state.checked argument
    onChange?: (selected: TYPE[]) => void;
    //all checkbox
    allButton?: boolean;
    //empty checkbox value
    emptyButton?: boolean;
    //label for empty checkbox
    emptyLabel?: string;
}

interface IMultiCheckboxState<TYPE> {
    values: SelectedValue<TYPE>[];
    all: boolean;
    empty: boolean;
}

interface SelectedValue<TYPE> {
    id: any;
    value: TYPE;
    selected: boolean;
}

class MultiCheckboxComponent<TYPE> extends Component<IMultiCheckboxProps<TYPE>, IMultiCheckboxState<TYPE>> {
    constructor(props: IMultiCheckboxProps<TYPE>) {
        super(props);

        // set the initial state
        this.state = {
            values: props.values.map(value => {
                return {
                    id: props.idFunc(value),
                    value: value,
                    selected: props.initialChecked == null ? false : this.props.initialChecked
                };
            }),
            all: props.initialChecked == null ? false : this.props.initialChecked,
            empty: false
        };
    }

    /*
       * Render the component as ReactElement
       */
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        console.log('render')
        console.log(this.state);
        const id = 'multicheckbox-' + this.props.id;
        const subId = id + '-checkbox-';
        var checkboxes = this.state.values.map(value =>
            <Checkbox
                key={subId + value.id}
                id={subId + value.id}
                name={this.props.labelFunc(value.value)}
                checked={value.selected}
                showLabel={true}
                value={value.value}
                labelFunc={this.props.labelFunc}
                cross={this.props.cross}
                disabled={this.props.disabled}
                onChange={(state) => this.onCheckboxChanged(state.checked, state.value)}
            />
        );

        if (this.props.allButton) {
            checkboxes = checkboxes.concat(
                <Checkbox
                    key={subId + 'all'}
                    id={subId + 'all'}
                    name={'Alle'}
                    value={'Alle'}
                    showLabel={true}
                    labelFunc={(value) => value}
                    cross={this.props.cross}
                    disabled={this.props.disabled}
                    checked={this.state.all}
                    onChange={(state) =>
                        this.setAllChecked(state.checked)
                    }
                />
            );
        }

        if (this.props.emptyButton) {

        }

        console.log(checkboxes);

        return (
            <div
                id={id}
                key={id}
            >{checkboxes}</div>
        );
    }

    private onCheckboxChanged(checked: boolean, value: TYPE): void {
        alert(value.toString() + ' is checked: ' + checked);
        //TODO set boolean true/false on this.state.values -> checked!
    }

    private setAllChecked(checked: boolean): void {
        console.log(checked);
        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
            values: this.state.values.map(val => {
                return {
                    id: val.id,
                    value: val.value,
                    selected: checked
                };
            }),
            all: checked,
            empty: this.state.empty
        }, this.onSelectedChanged);
    }

    private onSelectedChanged(): void {
        if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(this.state.values.map(value => {
                return value.value
            }));
        }
    }

}

export const MultiCheckbox = (MultiCheckboxComponent);
```

And my main problem is that whenever I click on the "All-Checkbox" the other entries are not updated...
The state get's changed on the "MultiCheckboxComponent", but the "constructor" is not called on the "Checkbox", so it's state is not updated and rerendered correctly. I am new to React and I want to create a component without "redux-store" which can be used on different forms (local-store) and populates it's values/states upwards to a more specific component which stores it in redux.

Like:

1. `FooComponent (list of Foo) -> MultiCheckboxComponent -> multiple Checkboxes`
2. `FeeComponent (list of Fee) -> MultiCheckboxComponent -> multiple Checkboxes`
3. `LuuComponent (stuff) -> single Checkbox`

But whenever I call "setState()" on the MultiCheckboxComponent the "render" happens, and render also happens on CheckboxComponent, but the "props" are not used ("Constructor" not called). How can I set the state on the "Child" from the "Parent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're having trouble because you're thinking about how these sort of things should be modelled in react in slightly the wrong way.

The constructor is only called once - when the component is created. I don't think the state inside your checkbox components is necessary - after all - they seem to be pretty much duplicating the props.

When you write React code - think of your props as changing values that will trigger updates in your child components. Use these to affect how the component looks.

Here's some changes I'd make:

- Get rid of the checkbox state - you probably don't need it
- Because you don't need state, you can write a pure functional component (stateless). This makes your code easier to reason about as there are less moving parts
- Destructure your props to save repeating this.props.X
- Use shortcircuiting to reduce verboseness (returning a falsey value to the renderer ignores it - more on this here https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

This leaves you with the following:

```
interface ICheckboxProps<TYPE> {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  value: TYPE;
  checked?: boolean;
  //if a cross should be used instead of a hook
  cross?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  //should show a label on the right side of the checkbox
  showLabel?: boolean;
  //get the string for the value of the checkbox
  labelFunc?: (value: TYPE) => string;
  // an onChange function which gets called with the state.checked argument
  onChange?: (checkbox: ICheckboxState<TYPE>) => void;
}

function CheckboxComponent<TYPE>(props: ICheckboxProps<TYPE>) {
  console.log('Checkbox render: ');
  // Destructure props - save writing out this.props.foo each time
  const { name, id, cross, onChange, checked, disabled, showLabel } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className="checkbox">
      <input
        id={id}
        type="checkbox"
        name={name}
        className={cross ? 'checkbox-cross' : 'checkbox-hook'}
        onChange={(e) => onChange && onChange(e.target.checked)}
        checked={checked}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
      {showLabel && (
        <label className="checkbox-label" htmlFor={id}>
          {labelFunc ? labelFunc(value) : value}?
        </label>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export const Checkbox = (CheckboxComponent);
```

Let me know if you need any further help with this!

Comment: But doing it like this I cannot use the checkbox as an uncontrolled component anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - It's not currently an uncontrolled component. To have the component as uncontrolled is to allow the DOM to be the single source of truth - which you then retrieve values from at the point you need it (i.e, after you're done with the form). At the moment your state is (somewhat) controlled by the parent - at least it's stored in the parent - but the link to update the value in the child is broken.

Comment: See more on uncontrolled components here. You use a ref to pull the value from the DOM https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html